# How can I remove duplicate files across separate directory trees?

Tags: linux

I have two directories: `old/` and `new/`.  Some of the files in `old/` are duplicates of those in `new/`.  Some merely have the same name, and a few may even have identical content but different names.  I'm not interested in the subdirectory path to the files, so only an unqualified filename needs to be considered in the matching.

I want to remove the duplicate files from `old/`, so that it only contains files not also found in `new/`.  For cases where the filenames match, but not the contents, or vice-versa, I want to have this listed in some log.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem, or have a better solution than hacking together a (perl or similar) script from scratch?  A runtime dominated by calling `md5sum` on each file is acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course! Check out [FSlint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/):

> FSlint is a utility to find and clean
>   various forms of lint on a filesystem.
>   I.E. unwanted or problematic cruft in
>   your files or file names. **For example,
>   one form of lint it finds is duplicate
>   files.** It has both GUI and command
>   line modes.

[image]

FSlint is free and open source software.

Comment: That looks close enough for what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**[fdupes](http://code.google.com/p/fdupes/) - finds duplicate files in a given set of directories**

```
fdupes new/ old/
```

-d for delete

-N for don't ask

```
fdupes -N -d new/ old/
```

Comment: Won't this also find (and delete) duplicates within each directory? In other words, if new (or old) happens to contain duplicate files that may or may not be found within old, those would be deleted too? I don't think fdupes is strictly a diffing program as implied by your arguments "new" and "old".