# Remove duplicated images with the shell

Tags: shell, images, duplicate

I have a folder with osme images. Each of them has a different name but some of them are duplicate.

What is the best way to delete the duplicates? I have to do it sistematically so I need some shell command/script to invoke.

No limitation of used software, just no strange software..

I'd like to do it both in a Mac and in a Ubuntu systems

Comment: See also [Find Duplicate Files (based on MD5 hash) -- For Mac OS X](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10039/find-duplicate-files-based-on-md5-hash-for-mac-os-x) and [Find Duplicate Files (based on size first, then MD5 hash)](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3555/find-duplicate-files-based-on-size-first-then-md5-hash). Notably, OS X uses `md5` while Linux uses `md5sum`.

Comment: Also: [What is the best method to remove duplicate image files from your computer](http://superuser.com/questions/152531/what-is-the-best-method-to-remove-duplicate-image-files-from-your-computer/152534#152534), and [Remove duplicate files across separate directory trees](http://superuser.com/questions/107550/remove-duplicate-files-across-separate-directory-trees/109760#109760)